# Selection by primary key and other indexes

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Suppose I have millions of rows in my table. The table has the primary key (pk is indexed by default in postgresql) on the `id` column.

Also the table has some additional columns like `year`, `name`, `phone` and something else.

I want to find row by id or group of ids and `year` column like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE year = '1996' AND id = 123123
```

or like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE year = '1996' AND id IN (123123, 456456, 789789)
```

Should I create an index on `year` column if I have primary key on `id`? What type of indexing more effective for this case?

What if I had only two years in my table (for example 1996 and 1997), it would be better if I created index on `year` column?

Comment: Don't compare numbers and strings. `'1996'` is a string value, not a number. Some DBMS might not use an index lookup if you don't use a constant value that matches the column's data type (although for just two different years in "millions" of rows, an index would hardly be chosen anyway).

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to create index for your scenario. ID is primary key and index on ID will be always used when you mix it with Year (using AND).

Comment: At least as it is AND year. (OR would be something quite different.)

Comment: @jarlh Yes. But OP is not asking about OR. When there will be OR and there are only 2 Year values in the table then FULL SCAN will be used.

Comment: I just wanted to add that extra info, since you said "mix it with year". It's good to know that it depends on how you mix.

Comment: Ok I added clarification.

Comment: @dcieslak Thanks for answering. Could I ask you some questions? I think I don't understand something. If I have 100000000 rows, that O(n) is 19 of B-tree indexing. Suppose I have only 100 years and add index on `year` column. Now I have a million rows in each year (for example we have a million rows for each year), and now O(n) is 14, aren't it? It would be better if I want to find all rows of some year. Could you explain me where I was wrong?

Comment: @Leonard  You're not wrong, however the index choices will always depend on the queries you want.   You've only given examples that include specific primary key values, so no other index is needed.

Comment: A small clarification, not all rows of some year, but a part of rows of some year. For example, I want to find a name for each item of list which contains ```ids``` only for a one ```year```. It would be faster if I found all rows of necessary ```year``` and then start find necessary ```ids```. And would be slowly if I found all rows which contains necessary ```ids``` and then find necessary ```year```.

Comment: @Leonard Accessing data by index means reading one row. When you do full scan then you read multiple rows during one access. It will be most probably more efficient to read the whole table than using index just for only 100 distinct values in the year.  The other story is partitioning the table by year. It would be the most efficient for your last scenario.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have a PK defined, you shouldn't need an index on ONLY that field. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html

"PostgreSQL automatically creates an index for each unique constraint and primary key constraint to enforce uniqueness. Thus, it is not necessary to create an index explicitly for primary key columns."

2) However, if you need to regularly sort on year AND id, I'd recommend creating an index that includes both. I've found PG performs better when you get the order of the index the right way around e.g. I had a table with store_number and product_number in it, which had the same product in multiple stores. It worked a heck of a lot better with store_number first because that was a common filter for user queries, and cut the recordset down by millions - there are more products than stores!

3) I'd suggest altering year to be integer. Makes it easier to do logical operations.